# How do I finish proving this inequality?

Tags: inequality

> Given $a, b,c >0$ satisfying $abc=1$. Prove that: $\dfrac{1}{{{a^2} + 2{b^2} + 3}} + \dfrac{1}{{{b^2} + 2{c^2} + 3}} + \dfrac{1}{{{c^2} + 2{a^2} + 3}} \le \dfrac{1}{2}$?

This is my try:

Using the AM–GM inequality, I get: $a^2+b^2 \ge 2ab$ and $b^2+1 \ge 2b$

Therefore, $a^2+2b^2+1 \ge 2ab+2b$ which implies that: $a^2+2b^2+3 \ge 2(ab+b+1)$

Hence, $\dfrac{1}{a^2+2b^2+3} \le \dfrac{1}{2(ab+b+1)}$

Doing the same, I get $\dfrac{1}{b^2+2c+3} \le \dfrac{1}{2(bc+c+1)}$ and $\dfrac{1}{c^2+2a+3} \le \dfrac{1}{2(ca+a+1)}$

Thus,
$\dfrac{1}{a^2+2b^2+3}+\dfrac{1}{b^2+2c^2+3}+\dfrac{1}{c^2+2a^2+3}\le\dfrac{1}{2(ab+b+1)}+\dfrac{1}{2(bc+c+1)}+\dfrac{1}{2(ca+a+1)}$

I know this is really close to the answer but something messed with my brain and I cannot think any further. How do I continue and is there any better solution than this?

Comment: FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%5E2%20%2B%202b%5E2%20%2B%203%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bb%5E2%20%2B%202c%5E2%20%2B%203%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bc%5E2%20%2B%202a%5E2%20%2B%203%7D%20%5Cle%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%24&p=1), I found the AoPS threads [If abc \geq 1, show that cyclic sum 1/(a^2+2b^2+3) \leq 1/2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1658218p10515177) and [Help me this inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1670607p10626779).

Comment: And here is a similar problem on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/624637. The final step is the same as in your question.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: You are probably aware of it, but just in case: One can restrict Approach0 search results to Math.SE with `AND site:math.stackexchange.com`, see example #2 at the end of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Actually, I wasn't aware of that feature. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Snek Are you wanting $ a^2 + 2b^{\color{red}2} + 3$ or $ a^2 + 2b + 3 $? It seems to just be a typo to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done all the hard work! Now you only need to prove $$\frac{1}2\left(\frac{1}{ab+b+1}+\frac{1}{bc+c+1}+\frac{1}{ca+a+1}\right)\leq\frac{1}2$$

---

**HINT:** utilize $abc=1$.
$$\frac{1}{ab+b+1}=\frac{c}{abc+bc+c}=\frac{c}{1+bc+c}$$

$$\frac{1}{ca+a+1}=\frac{bc}{abc^2+abc+bc}=\frac{bc}{c+1+bc}$$

Therefore, $$\frac{1}{ab+b+1}+\frac{1}{bc+c+1}+\frac{1}{ca+a+1}=?$$